# Cut and paste a specific row based on user input in the same excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select the last row of data in the wooksheet in my case excel row 999. My macro does the following:

1. user gets a dialog box asking where in the same worksheet the row should be pasted based on the "Excel" row number. (see code below)

For example row 999 is cut and then pasted between rows 4 and 5.

This works fine, but at the moment to paste between rows 4 & 5 the user has to input the text 5:5

I would like the user to be able to simply enter a number 5, 10, 100, etc.. in the dialog box. Any ideas of how to do this much appreciated.

> Blockquote

```
'Input paste location, defaut value row 5

Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("Input row", "Input", ("5:5"))


' Select row, cut row 999, paste cut row based on input dialog

Rows("999:999").Select
Selection.Cut
Rows(myValue).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

[image: Sample fro OP]

Comment: Now all we would like to see is the code you have produced by your own effort to arrive at a solution (working or not). [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Sorry new to the site I have reworked the question and added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered my own question. It acually works as it stands when you enter a row number eg 5, 6, 10, 100, etc..

Fantastic

The updated code below excludes the "5:5" default value.

> Blockquote

```
'Input paste location, defaut value row 5

Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("Insert New Row", "Input", ("5"))

   If myValue = "" Then Exit Sub

' Select row, cut row 999, paste cut row based on input dialog

Rows("999:999").Select
Selection.Cut
Rows(myValue).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```